# Why will React Context only fire passed down value functions from DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use React Context to update the login/logout functionality of my web app. As this isn't a high traffic function to call, I thought a perfect opportunity to use the context API, create my provider, and tap into the provider in the necessary component down the chain.

Unfortunately, it appears I can't use any of the passed down functions in a component function, like handleSubmit() for example. They work great if I call them directly from a DOM element (examples below).

I'm thinking this is some kind of "this" error, and the DOM call is using a different scope than in component.

Any help on why this is happening and how to fix it would be great.

Thanks!

Context:

```
export const LoginContext = React.createContext({});
export class LoginCtx extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            login: () => this.login,
            logout: () => this.logout
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    login(user) {
        console.log('Inside Login:', user);
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
    }

    logout() {
        console.log('Inside Logout');
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LoginContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </LoginContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Form:

```
const C = ({ classes }) => {
    const { login } = useContext(LoginContext);

    const initialValues = {
        email: 'abc@test.com',
        password: '',
        remember: false
    };

    const dummySubmit = async (values, actions) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        if (values.email === 'abc@test.com') {

            // THIS ONE WONT FIRE THE LOGIN COMMAND
            login();
        }
        actions.setSubmitting(false);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => dummySubmit(values, actions)}
            >
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form className={classes.form}>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                name='email'
                                type='email'
                                placeholder='Email'
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name='email' component='div' />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                name='password'
                                type='password'
                                placeholder='Password'
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name='email' component='div' />
                        </div>
                        <button type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>

            {/* THIS ONE DOES FIRE THE LOGIN COMMAND */}
            <button onClick={login()}>Login Ctx</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    login: () => this.login,
    logout: () => this.logout
};
```

The functions you've created here do nothing, except return a reference to `this.login`/`this.logout`. As it stands, the components farther down the component tree would have to call the function they get from context, and then call the function that's returned by the first call. For example:

```
const { login } = useContext(LoginContext);
// ...
login()();
```

Most likely, you either meant to do this:

```
this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    login: () => this.login(),
    logout: () => this.logout()
};
this.login = this.login.bind(this);
this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
```

Or this:

```
this.login = this.login.bind(this);
this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    login: this.login,
    logout: this.logout
};
```

Comment: Well, don't I feel like an idiot.

Everything is working as intended now. Thank you so much!